# What is the difference between a caesura and metrical silence in poetry?

Tags: poetry

I know both are a pause but I'm not sure if they refer to the same thing. I've been using a German book on poetry to help with my translation project. I've came across Zäsur which I found to be caesura. But an English book talks about metrical silence without (at least not yet) mentioning caesuras.

Answer (score 2):

Metrical silence and caesura do not refer to the same thing. They refer, as you note, to the same type of thing: they are types of pause.

A caesura (break or pause), falls outside the meter of the poem. It has no metrical value.

A metrical silence, on the other hand, is part of the meter of the poem, occurring when an unaccented syllable that is part of the metrical scheme is left out.

> Caesura (cesura). A rhetorical and *extra-metrical* pause or phrasal break within the poetic line.

(from **Princeton Encyclopedia of Poetry and Poetics: Enlarged Edition**, 1974; italics mine)

> metrical silence – a pause, like that in music, created when an unaccented syllable needed to complete the foot is omitted.

(from [POEMED](http://poemed.org/keyTerms.php#M))

For examples of the controversial nature of metrical silence due to scansion variability, see [A Note on the Scansion of Keats’s
“La Bella Dame Sans Merci”](http://web.nchu.edu.tw/~chtung/1979.doc), by Alexander Tung.